# How to print a list of Tools from their respective Toolboxes with arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arctoolbox

I would like to print a list of Toolboxes as listed in my Python code, however I would also like to print the tools in that Toolbox under neath the Toolbox name like so;

Analysis Tools(analysis)

Buffer_analysis

Clip_analysis

Data Management Tools(management)

DeleteRows_management

CopyRows_management

Here is the python code I have so far, but, when i run it it just prints a list of the Toolboxes without the tools that belong to them.
Here is my code;

```
 import arcpy
toolboxes = arcpy.ListToolboxes()
for toolbox in toolboxes:
print( toolbox)
toolbox = "Analysis Tools(analysis)" + \
"Data Management Tools(management)" + \
"3D Analyst Tools(3d)" + \
"Cartography Tools(cartography)" + \
"Conversion Tools(conversion)" + \
"Geocoding Tools(geocoding)" + \
"Geostatistical Analyst Tools(ga)" + \
"Linear Referencing Tools(Ir)" + \
"Spatial Analyst Tools(sa)" + \
"Spatial Statistics Tools(stats)" + \
"Coverage Tools(arc)"
startIndex = toolbox.find("(")
startIndex = toolbox.find("B")
tools = arcpy.ListTools("*_analysis" + \
"*_management" + \
"*_3d" + \
"*_cartography" + \
"*_conversion" + \
"*_geocoding" + \
"*_ga" + \
"*_Ir" + \
"*_sa" + \
"*_stats" + \
"*_arc")
print("/t + toolbox")
```

Comment: This could easily just be a formatting issue from when you copied and pasted the code into your original post, but is the formatting shown in your post how it is in your actual code or does your code include indentation (proper formatting)?

Comment: @John My formatting is correct however Could not seem to keep it in original formatting when i copied it over thank you for pointing it out. The code runs just fine just does not give me the desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, based on what I think you are asking for, I think all you should need is:

```
import arcpy
toolboxes = arcpy.ListToolboxes()
for toolbox in toolboxes:
    print toolbox
    tools = arcpy.ListTools('*_'+toolbox[toolbox.index('(')+1:toolbox.index(')')])
    for tool in tools:
        print tool
    print '\n'
```

Fair warning, this script will print every tool in every toolbox, so the script will take a little bit to run even assuming you just have all the default toolboxes ArcGIS Desktop installs.

If, as you commented, you want only the results for specific toolboxes, it would simply be a matter of adding an `if toolbox in listOfToolboxes:` statement.  It could look something like the following, where you would obviously adjust the list of toolboxes by customizing with your own list (only use the toolbox abbreviation, the part in parenthesis, in the list of toolboxes if using the code below).

```
import arcpy
toolboxes = arcpy.ListToolboxes()
for toolbox in toolboxes:
    tbAbrev = toolbox[toolbox.index('(')+1:toolbox.index(')')]
    if tbAbrev in ['sa','3d','management']:
        print toolbox
        print tbAbrev
        tools = arcpy.ListTools('*_'+tbAbrev)
        for tool in tools:
            print tool
        print '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you, however is there a way to list only the tools from the toolboxes I have listed? I appreciate the response

Comment: Just add an if conditional statement after the for loop over all toolboxes,e.g.  if toolbox = "Spatial Analyst Tools(sa)"